# jQuery .on() not behaving as I want

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to accomplish a feature on my site that shows/hides respective parts of my site depending on the value in a select dropdown.

HTML snippet:

```
<tr class="inputcontainer">
    <td class="label">Trade to:</td>
    <td class="input">
        <select data-group="tradeTo">
            <option value="1">Platinum</option>
            <option value="2">Keys</option>
            <option value="3">Mods</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td class="check"></td>
    <td class="errormessage"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="inputcontainer" id="trade_platinum" data-group="tradeTo" data-component="1">
    <td class="label">Platinum:</td>
    <td class="input"><input type="text" name="trade_platinum" value=""></td>
    <td class="check"></td>
    <td class="errormessage"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="inputcontainer" id="trade_keys" data-group="tradeTo" data-component="2">
    <td class="label">Key:</td>
    <td class="input"><select name="trade_keys" data-source="mod"></td>
    <td class="check"></td>
    <td class="errormessage"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="inputcontainer" id="trade_mods" data-group="tradeTo" data-component="3">
    <td class="label">Mod:</td>
    <td class="input"><select name="trade_mod" data-source="mod"></td>
    <td class="check"></td>
    <td class="errormessage"></td>
</tr>
```

It logically groups all elements with the same `data-group` such that they belong to the same class.
Then it only shows the elements of which the `data-component` is the `value` of the initial select option.

Snippet of JS which I do for all forms on my page (The HTML code is also embedded in a form):

```
function preprocess(form) {
    //...
    $(form).find("select").each(function() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        promises.push(deferred.promise());

        deferred = refreshSelect($(this), deferred);

        var select = $(this);
        var argument = $(this).data("argument");
        if (typeof argument !== 'undefined') {
            $(document).on("change", "#" + argument, function(event) {
                refreshSelect($(select));
            });
        }

        var group = $(this).data("group");
        if (typeof group !== 'undefined') {
            $(form).find("*[data-group='" + group + "'][data-component]").hide();
            $(form).find("*[data-group='" + group + "'][data-component=" + $(select).val() + "]").show();
            $(document).on("change", select, function(event) {
                $(form).find("*[data-group='" + group + "'][data-component]").hide();
                $(form).find("*[data-group='" + group + "'][data-component='" + $(select).val() + "']").show();
            });
        }
    });
}
```

In the bottom part I execute my logic, it is working actually okayish, however it is triggering on too much, note the following line:

`$(document).on("change", select, function(event) {`

I should be passing a **selector** to the `.on()` function and not an object, however how do I know which selector I need to pass?

The faulty behaviour as of is that it triggers on **all** `select` changes, instead of just the specified one.

Comment: Why not just do `select.on("change", function(event) { ... ` ??

Comment: Pointy has a... point.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks, it seems to be working exactly as expected now.